# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception (without Android Studio)

Tags: flutter

I'm currently learning Flutter with a low-end laptop where I cannot work with Android Studio. So I installed Flutter with VS Code editor and installed successfully. I can run Flutter commands and detect my real mobile device that is connected to my laptop. I created a test app with `flutter create testrun` command and the app build was success.

Below is the screenshot of it:

[image: app build]

But when I do `flutter run` command it gives me errors like this:

[image: error info]

I tried to resolve this error by research but most of them says to change something like distribution url in the `gradle-wrapper.properties`. But I can't do it without Android Studio.

In the error, it says that Java version is not compatible with flutter Gradle version. I have checked my Java version by running `flutter doctor --verbose` command and install the compatible Gradle and Java version by in the below link. Here I have to mention that I updated my Gradle manually.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

Here is the screenshot of `flutter doctor --verbose` command and Gradle version.

Gradle version screenshot:

[image: gradle version ss]

Flutter command screenshot:

[image: flutter cmd ss]

I want to know how to upgrade Gradle through flutter only if possible or how to upgrade my Gradle in my project. How can I set default gradle version in Flutter without using Android Studio? I don't want to update Gradle version every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced problem like this a while ago, while i was trying to build my android app.

You can try this:

1. Go to **gradle-wrapper.properties** in the **android/gradle** folder.
2. Look for the **distributionUrl** and update the gradle version number there.
3. Now you can run **"flutter build apk"**

You can try these. Let me know does this work for you or not!

Comment: Here is what i done. On _android/build.gradle_ updated the classpath dependency from **7.3.0** to **7.6.1** and _android/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties_ updated the distributionUrl from **https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip** to **https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip**

Comment: Here is the result of that.  `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.`

`* What went wrong:`  
`A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.`
`> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.`
   `> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1.`
     `Searched in the following locations:`
       `- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6.1/gradle-7.6.1.pom`
       `- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6.1/gradle-7.6.1.pom`
     `Required by:`
         `project :`

Comment: Did you update your classpath? It seems the issue occured while configuring the classpath.

Try changing like this:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1'

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip

Comment: ![Result after changing class path and distributionUrl like you mentioned](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ccS1MN0-2g_SQqee_BZwAPViASjRYgey/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Check the compatibility matrix between Java and Gradle versions from this. 

Link: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java

Then update the gradle version which is compatible with the gradle version.
Run "flutter run --verbose" to check your java version.